# Where is the web server when using a serverless database?

Tags: wordpress, serverless

now days it is very popular to see serverless databases.
My question is,where is the web server like e.g. Apache?
Is it possible to run e.g. wordpress or drupal using a serverless database?
What the architecture would be to run such an installation?
Thanks

Comment: What does a database have to do with a web server?

Comment: where the web server will be hosted?

Comment: The question is meaningless. A web server is an independent application that has nothing to do with the sql server. Where you will host the application (where the web server will be located) is irrelevant to whether or not the application itself uses a database served by a server.
Maybe you're not asking your question correctly.

Comment: So,apart from the (serverless) sql server,I need to host somewhere my web server.